# Spring boot Test multiple classes for API and repository

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

I write the test for the Spring Boot and have 2 classes that are testing the API and the repository. The skeletons are provided below,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AppointmentAPITest {


    /*
     * we need a system to simulate this behavior without starting a
     * full HTTP server. MockMvc is the Spring class that does that.
     * */
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AppointmentAPI api;


    // now the tests are going on

}
```

The repository test class,

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class AppointmentRepositoryTest {


    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentRepository repository;


    // write the test here 

}
```

How do I use a single class to run them all? For example, if the class will be `AppointmentApplicationTests`,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AppointmentApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

}
```

What will be the best way to configure this class so it calls all the tests in the API and repo classes?

Comment: How do you run tests now? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I run them individually from the each files. Do you need to see the tests inside the files as well?

Comment: No, I mean that do you just do something like "right click -> run as Junit test" or how?

Comment: Any build tool maven/gradle?

Comment: I use Maven for the build the app. I click the test sign on the top of the files and run the tests individually. I look for the option to run both classes (incl. all the tests) altogether.

Comment: What IDE do you use IDEA / Eclipse?

Comment: I use IntellIj IDEA ... I dont know if this is relevant though for this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think simpliest way would be to create a `Suite` to have a collection of tests to be run, like:

**JUnit 4**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    some.package.AppointmentRepositoryTest,
    some.package.AppointmentApplicationTests
})
public class MySuite {
}
```

**Junit5**

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({some.package.AppointmentRepositoryTest,
    some.package.AppointmentAPITest.class})
public class JUnit5TestSuiteExample {
}
```

However this is not alwasy the best way to do it. Consider also to get acquainted with howto create test profile for maven toe perform a bunch of tests or packages.

Comment: I need something like this but I get the error after I use the code-  `org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath`

Comment: @Arefe Just guessing but maybe you are trying to run junit5 while you should use that of 4? Think that spring-boot has 4. 5 is a bit different to 4, it needs more deps in your POM.

Comment: I just checked and the code for the `JUnit 4` works fine. The second annotation needs to be `@Suite.SuiteClasses({AppointmentRepositoryTest .class,AppointmentAPITest .class})` though.